# Spring Webflux: CoRouter CoRouterFunctionDsl (Coroutine)-context not applied to onError

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, micrometer-tracing

I am running web flux with Kotlin coroutines using spring boot 3.2 and the underlying version 6.1.1 of the spring framework.

I am using micrometer for tracing. With spring's `coRouter`, I followed the example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27010 to set the context in my corouter, so all subsequent calls have access to the `MdcContext`.

But if I define an `onError` function, the context is not applied to that function. Is there a special way to do that, or do I have to send the context manually as a function parameter?

Example:

```
@Bean
fun demoRoutes() = coRouter {
    "/rest".nest {
        "v1".nest {
            "/demo".nest {
                context { observationRegistry.asContextElement() }
                GET("", demoHandler::demoCall)
            }
        }
    }
    onError<RuntimeException> { throwable, serverRequest ->
        errorHandler.handleError(throwable, serverRequest)
    }
}
```

Another additional question:
Is there some way to make the `context` apply for everything? It only applies if it is set in the last `nest` function. If I define it to a parent or directly within `coRouter`, it's not working:

```
@Bean
fun demoRoutes() = coRouter {
    context { observationRegistry.asContextElement() }
    "/rest".nest {
        "v1".nest {
            "/demo".nest {
                GET("", demoHandler::demoCall)
            }
        }
    }
    onError<RuntimeException> { throwable, serverRequest ->
        errorHandler.handleError(throwable, serverRequest)
    }
}
```

If used like that, the context is lost in the call to `demoHandler::demoCall`.

Comment: Looks like indeed meaningful questions, I will try to answer shortly, so not sure why those votes.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of error handling seems to be ok as far as I can tell, but there is indeed a surprising behavior when combining nested routers and `CoroutineContext`, this should be fixed by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31831.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nesting now works as expected with the last snapshot of 6.1.2
But I still don't get the context in the error handler, see https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/174#issuecomment-1854976638